# Jquery Function running multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using two scripts on my page and there is a general click function which records the number of clicks one user is making. So when I click on any element in the document, the click function should run after which other functions on the same element runs. But in my case, the click function runs multiple times before passing the control to the other function.

```
/************ 1st Jquery Script ***************/
    function($) {
      $(function(e) {
       $('.signupCustom').click(function(){
        var email = $('#form-email').val()
        var password = $('#pass').val()
        var firstName= $('#form-first-name').val()
        var lastName= $('#form-last-name').val()
        var number= $('#form-mobile').val()
        var type=$('#sel1').val()

        $.ajax({
            url: '/login',
            type: 'GET',
            data: {
                'email': email,
                'password':password,
                'firstName':firstName,
                'lastName':lastName,
                'number':number,
                'type':type
            },
            success: function(data){
                if ($('#sel1').val() == "Travel-Agent"){
                    window.location.href = "/agentVerification.html"
                }
                else{
                    window.location.href = "/dashboardTraveller"
                }
            }
        })
    })

    $('.login').click(function(){
        var email = $('#form-username').val()
        var password= $('#form-password').val()
        $.ajax({
            url: '/loginCustom',
            type: 'GET',
            data: {
                'email': email,
                'password':password
            },
            success: function(data){
                window.location.href = data['url']
            }
        })
    })

    $('.destinationsButton').click(function(){

        var url="/destinations";
        window.location=url;
    })


});   })(jQuery);
```

I have attached the link to the  html page which contains the second script.

[**Link to Page**](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B08OnKHLvyhmUE1uNmFEWWZaTE0/view?usp=sharing)

If you go to this link, there is an image:

[image]

When I click on Login button, the click function runs multiple times before control goes to other function. I want the click function to run single time and then control should go to other function.

I tried `e.stopPropagation` but in case of a popup on same page, the popup does not open. Here on clicking on login, popup comes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there any reason you are using the below?

```
jQuery('*').on("click",function(e){});
```

I think this might work better

```
jQuery('body').on("click",function(e){});
```

good luck

Comment: Yes, there was a reason, i want to detect every click made inside the document. So thats why i used this.

Comment: Thanks Chrishtopher, i made the particular edit, it worked...........thanks a lot :)

Comment: The reason this was firing multiple times is all the wrappers also have the event bubbled to them when the '*' was used - so every wrapper got the event triggered also.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where you're stuck but you may use [one](http://api.jquery.com/one) to run the click function just once:

```
$(selector).one('click',function(){
   //code runs only one click
});
```